# Bootstrap 3 form into modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have a form in modal window and it looks like this:
Here you can see that input fields are really small...

[image]

Also the same code but not in modal widnow: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/37/edit
Works fine.

What is the problem here?

Why can't I show the form like on my example without modal window?

How can I solve it?

I tried to remove `div class=col-md-4`, but again it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you want exactly? You want form in a modal window? You want a form with small fields? Or you want a form normally but with small fields?

Comment: I want to show form like on my example: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/37

Comment: so I need look like on my example http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/37, when I open modal window...

Comment: can you share the link where u have this exact problem. Maybe create a fiddle or at the least share some code ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the page where you are getting the problem? If it's working fine on jsbin, we don't need to look at jsbin but your code on that specific page.

Comment: ok, on agroagro.com/app.html click on button "Add new"

Comment: http://www.agroagro.com/app.html click on green button Add new...

Comment: anybody know what is problem?

Comment: yes @sakir gives right answer just try it.

Answer (score 2):

generated html is like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="appendedtext"></label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="appendedtext" name="appendedtext" class="form-control" placeholder="Ar" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Ar</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

try to change `col-md-2` to `col-md-4` or just remove it